# react query how to disable fetch on new instances

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-query

I'm using react query, and I see (from the docs and from trying) that react query refetches on every new instance of useQuery. If I don't want this feature, how can I disable it?

Comment: Are you looking for refetchOnMount?

Comment: No, the opposite, I want the query to refetch (maybe from other components) but I don't want that component to rebuild

Answer (score 0):

you can use `enabled` is `false` then The query will not automatically refetch in the background when new instances mount or new instances appear

this is react query example

```
     function Todos() {
2   const {
3     isIdle,
4     isLoading,
5     isError,
6     data,
7     error,
8     refetch,
9     isFetching,
10   } = useQuery('todos', fetchTodoList, {
11     enabled: false,
12   })
13 
14   return (
15     <>
16       <button onClick={() => refetch()}>Fetch Todos</button>
17 
18       {isIdle ? (
19         'Not ready...'
20       ) : isLoading ? (
21         <span>Loading...</span>
22       ) : isError ? (
23         <span>Error: {error.message}</span>
24       ) : (
25         <>
26           <ul>
27             {data.map(todo => (
28               <li key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</li>
29             ))}
30           </ul>
31           <div>{isFetching ? 'Fetching...' : null}</div>
32         </>
33       )}
34     </>
35   )
36 }
```

you just need to write some `if` conditions for `enable` to don't refatch in new instances that appear in your condition

Comment: I'm using custom hooks and those hooks can be run in multiple places. Isn't there a way to say inside that hook to run only on the first initialization?

Comment: oh I see in this situation you need to use
`refetchOnWindowFocus: false,`